# Can we automatically label device tree with symbols?

Tags: device-tree

Is it possible to use [device tree compiler](https://manpages.org/dtc) to automatically label nodes when generating device tree source from device tree binary/source?

I can assign the labels from the symbols to their respectful node paths using `dtc -A` for example. I would like the output of the tree to be from this Device Tree

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
   {
      node@10000000 {};
   }
   __symbols__ {
      label = /node@10000000;
   };
};
```

to this Device Tree

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
   {
      label: node@10000000 {};
   }
   __symbols__ {
      label = /node@10000000;
   };
};
```